# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de una celda de un datatable en PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Tengo una columna que se llama "fecha termino" y quiero que cuando este a 4 días de vencer me pinte de color anaranjado y cuando este a 2 días de vencer me pinte de color rojo la celda especificada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa http://stackoverflow.com/q/13014770

Comment: Libra, puedes colgar el `xhtml` donde printas la tabla y los hexadecimales de los colores para responderte bien???  PD: @LuiggiMendoza que grande que es BalusC...

Comment: @JordiCadilla si, BalusC es experto en JavaSE y JSF

Answer (score 1):

Si estas utilizando primefaces, puedes utilizar el atributo `styleClass` en la celda con una expresion EL para asi aplicar la clase segun la linea. Te recomiendo que en el bean que utilices, añadas otro atributo para almacenar el calculo, que lo prodras hacer en la base de datos. Si tiene menos de 4 dias, entonces lo marcas como 'A', y si no, como 'R' si queda menos de dos. Si no cumple ninguna condicion, pones 'B'.

La expresion EL seria algo asi.

```
styleClass="#{varDataTable.colorStyle eq 'A' ? 'styleYellow' : varDataTable.colorStyle eq 'R' ? 'styleRed' : null}"
```

Tienes que definir las clases css styleYellow y styleRed, pero este approach es bastante sencillo de realizar.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que sería un poco más fácil si hubieras puesto código... pero de cualquier manera, la idea en esencia es la misma, llenar condicionalmente la propiedad `style`.

```
<p:column headerText="fecha termino">
                    <h:outputText id="track"
                        value="#{mbLicencias.fechaTermino}"
                        style="color:#{mbLicencias.calculaColor()};" />
.
.
.
```

Y en tu clase

```
boolean vencido=false;
public String calcula color(mbLicencias licenciaAComprobar){
 //evaluar la fecha si faltan menos de dos días y decidir si vencido es true o false
 if( vencido ){
  return "ff0000";
 }else{
  return "000000";
 }
}
```

Si necesitas más colores puedes usar un switch.
Saludos.

Comment: Cuidado. Revisa el HTML generado por PrimeFaces y JSF. Para el código que colocas, sólo va a colocar el color al texto del `<h:outputText>` cuando el autor requiere que el color aplique a la celda. Te recomiendo que revises la respuesta de BalusC sobre este problema que coloqué en el comentario a la pregunta.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza en la pregunta dice color, no color de fondo, si quien pregunta desea algo más preciso, que lo especifique o ponga su código. Saludos.

Comment: Estaba explícito desde la primera versión de la pregunta...

Comment: Se observa en ambas versiones que dice color y no color de fondo. @LuiggiMendoza podrías sugerir una edición al autor para que cambir en su pregunta la parte que dice `color de celda` por `color de fondo de celda`. Saludos

Comment: El autor en la pregunta original pide cambiar el color a la columna. Eso lo explica.

Comment: Efectivamente, el color, **pero no el color de fondo**. Saludos.